# Usage of implication arrow in proof steps vs. in logical statements

Tags: logic, notation

The implication sign $\implies$ is right associative as I read in multiple sources. (e.g. this [answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/1853892/96731))

Here $A \implies B \implies C$ means:
$$A \implies (B \implies C)$$

But I also see common practices in proof where we chain each step via $\implies$.
(e.g. an excerpt [here](https://www.math.cmu.edu/%7Emradclif/teaching/127S19/Notes/Logic%20and%20Proof.pdf))
[image]
Here $A \implies B \implies C$ means:
$$(A \implies B) \wedge (B \implies C)$$

**Questions**

1. How do we distinguish between these two cases?
2. What's the alternative to $\implies$ (if it's ambiguous to use)? E.g. `thus`, `∴`, are they interchangeable?

Comment: In informal context it denotes a chain of related sequential steps. No real issue...

Comment: "Thus", "Therefore", "Hence", "which implies", and some others are all standard alternatives to $\implies$.  It is common, and often overlooked, that each $\implies$ might be assumed to mean that everything before it implies what follows it. E.g. it may be that $A\implies (A\land B)\implies C$ but that $B$ by itself does not imply $C,$ but someone might  write $A\implies  B\implies C$ and get away with it.

Comment: My reply to #1 is [Associativity of logical connectives](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/4260588/21813). My reply to #2 is [Implies doesn't mean Therefore](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/3891518/21813).

Answer (score 1):

My logics teachers always told me to differentiate them by using $\rightarrow$ for logical statements and $\Rightarrow$ for proof steps

Also, $A\rightarrow B\rightarrow C$ doesn't exist as a logical statement, it's either $(A\rightarrow B)\rightarrow C$ or $A\rightarrow (B\rightarrow C)$

For example, a theorem would use $\Rightarrow$ (like '$\forall n (n\in\mathbb{N}\rightarrow n≥0)$' ) and a proof of a theorem would use $\Rightarrow$ to guide the reader through its steps